# Does Quidditch affect life after Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

In the Muggle world there are an array of sports that you can play in school, such as football, basketball, netball, etc.  Colleges interviews (and even  employment interviews) will often examine your sports-playing during this time and take this into account.

In the Harry Potter world, how does being on a Quidditch team affect anything later on? Or does Quidditch change nothing if you aren't going to become a Quidditch player later in life?

Comment: Bagman is an ex-school-and-then-professional Quidditch player and now head of a major sporting ministry

Comment: I've never been interviewed about my school sports (or lack thereof). Then again, I know that this *is* a thing in the US - but is it also the case for the UK where Hogwarts is?

Comment: The playing fields of Eton were certainly considered useful once upon a time…

Comment: You'll live on in the Trophy Room and current students might take inspiration from you? (James/Harry)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen correct. In the UK, you won't get people trying to headhunt good school sports players and poach them to other schools/colleges/universities like how it appears in the US.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Not that we know of**

The short answer is we have nothing canon backing up Hogwart's Quidditch being useful for getting a non-sports-related job.

That being said Quidditch is such a big deal in the wizarding world, and the wizarding world seems to work almost exclusively by "old boy's club"* networks.  So a good quidditch player (or even somebody merely average who was on a house team) might be able to leverage that into a job. "Oh you were a Ravenclaw beater?? I was a Hufflepuff beater! We beaters have to stick together right? *gives job*"   "I was on the Slytherine Quidditch team too! Harry Potter wasn't that great a seeker, it was just the broom. Welcome aboard! *gives job*"

*Old Boy's Club is the phenomena wherein being a graduate of a school or member of an organization gives you preferential treatment by other graduates/members, even if they don't actually know you.  That's the basic idea.  While Old Boy's Club is gendered, it does not  preclude women being part of said networks (though often such networks do exclude women).